# Specs of the XT30 port on DJI M600 PRO

Tags: dji, compatibility, spec-sheet

I'm new here and so I would appreciate any answers,
I work in a research laboratory at Brazil and we have an [M600 PRO](https://www.dji.com/br/matrice600-pro).

I need to connect some components to the XT 30 port, so I need to know more information about this port. Power, maximum current supported, voltage, electrical diagram, compatibility, and all possible information about the capacity XT 30 port.

I'll use several components with maximum current estimated 7 A.

I had read several [datasheets](https://www.dji.com/br/matrice600-pro/info#downloads) but the only information that I found is maximum current supported 10 A and 18 V. So, I would like to know more information about the XT30.

I would be so glad with your help.
Have a nice week.

Answer (score 1):

Your question asks about the XT30 connector. I found this diagram which lists the specs of the XT30 connector:

[image: xt30]

However, [this source](https://forum.dji.com/thread-83312-1-1.html) suggests that the Matrice 600 pro has an XT60, not an XT30. It wouldn't make a difference in power though, as you are correct that the Matrice 600 can only supply 10 Amps and 18 Volts for a total of 180 Watts. This means that the only difference between using an XT30 and an XT60 would be the size of the connector. You can tell which connector it uses by looking at the side of the connector, in small letters it will say either XT30 or XT60.

The specs of the XT60 are as follows:

[image: XT60]

If your total power draw will be 7A at 18V, it should work fine. Just make sure that the total wattage you are trying to pull is under 180W.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i'm so glad for this information.